# total substrings with k ones

Tags: string, algorithm

Given a binary string s, we need to find the number of its substrings, containing exactly k characters that are '1'.

For example: s = "1010" and k = 1, answer = 6.

Now, I solved it using binary search technique over the cumulative sum array.

I also used another approach to solve it. The approach is as follows:

1. For each position i, find the total substrings that end at i containing
   exactly k characters that are '1'.
2. To find the total substrings that end at i containing exactly k characters that are 1, it can be represented as the set of indices j such that substring j to i contains exactly k '1's. The answer would be the size of the set. Now, to find all such j for the given position i, we can rephrase the problem as finding all j such that

number of ones from [1] to [j - 1] = the total number of ones from 1 to i - [the total number of ones from j to i = k].

i.e. number of ones from [1] to [j - 1] = C[i] - k

which is equal to 
C[j - 1] = C[i] - k,

where C is the cumulative sum array, where 
C[i] = sum of characters of string from 1 to i. 
Now, the problem is easy because, we can find all the possible values of j's using the equation by counting all the prefixes that sum to C[i] - k.

But I found this solution,

```
int main() {
    cin >> k >> S;
    C[0] = 1;
    for (int i = 0; S[i]; ++i) {
        s += S[i] == '1';
        ++C[s];
    }
    for (int i = k; i <= s; ++i) {
        if (k == 0) {
            a += (C[i] - 1) * C[i] / 2;
        } else {
            a += C[i] * C[i - k];
        }
    }
    cout << a << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

In the code, S is the given string and K as described above, C is the cumulative sum array and a is the answer.
What is the code exactly doing by using multiplication, I don't know.
Could anybody explain the algorithm?

Comment: I just understood the k = 0 part, if k = 0, since c[i] is the number of occurrences of cumulative sum equal to i, we must have (c[i] - 1) zeroes adjacent in the substring. So, the number of possible substrings that sum to zero = (c[i] - 1) * (c[i] - 1 + 1) / 2 = c[i] * (c[i] - 1) / 2, counts the number of possible substrings of a string  with all characters zeroes.

Comment: I think I got the other part too.

Answer (score 1):

If you see the way `C[i]` is calculated, `C[i]` represents the number of characters between `i`th `1` and `i+1`st `1`.

If you take an example `S = 1001000`

```
                   C[0] = 1 
                   C[1] = 3 // length of 100
                   C[2] = 4 // length of 1000
```

So coming to your doubt, **Why multiplication**

Say your `K=1`, then you want to find out the substring which have only one `1`, now you know that after first `1` there are two zeros `since C[1] = 3`. So number of of substrings will be 3, because you have to include this 1.

```
       {1,10,100}
```

But when you come to the second part: `C[2] =4`

now if you see `1000` and you know that you can make 4 substrings (which is equal to C[2])

```
     {1,10,100,1000}
```

and also you should notice that there are `C[1]-1` zeroes before this `1`.

So by including those zeroes you can make more substring, in this case by including `0` once

```
      0{1,10,100,1000}
      => {01,010,0100,01000}
```

and `00` once

```
      00{1,10,100,1000}
      => {001,0010,00100,001000}
```

so essentially you are making `C[i]` substrings starting with `1` and you can append `i` number of zeroes before this one and make another `C[i] * C[i-k]-1` substrings. `i varies from 1 to C[i-k]-1` (-1 because  we want to leave that last one).

```
   ((C[i-k]-1)* C[i]) +C[i]
   => C[i-k]*C[i]
```